# Postgresql how to do min and max with the name beside the value

Tags: postgresql, max, min

[this is the data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHpPt.jpg)

how to do to get below result:

[Here is the result i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGXbV.png)

I only can get lowest and highest without (name), any ideas to get above result?

Comment: In SQL you can do it  like -- `SELECT DISTINCE(SUBJECTS),MAX(SUBJECT),MIN(SUBJECT) FROM TABLE_NAME`

Comment: use proper tags, dont use multiple db tags for same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUP BY for grouping the subjects and then fetch max_mark, min_mark using MAX(), MIN() functions respectively

```
    SELECT subject AS "sub1", 
    MAX(scc) AS "max_mark", 
    MIN(scc) AS "min_mark"
    FROM Subjects_mark
    GROUP BY 1
```

Now use subquery for formatting the output

```
SELECT sub1, 
CONCAT(min_mark,'(',studentnar,')') AS "lowest point",
CONCAT(max_mark,'(',studentnar,')') AS "highest point"
FROM Subjects_mark AS s1
JOIN (
        SELECT subjects AS "sub1", 
        MAX(scc) AS "max_mark", 
        MIN(scc) AS "min_mark"
        FROM Subjects_mark
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS dt
ON dt.sub1 = s1.subjects 
AND dt.max_mark = s1.scc
```